# Prevent TD onclick from firing if a checkbox is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event that does this:

```
$('table tbody td').click( function (e) {
   // How to check if checkbox was clicked before doing the alert below?
   alert("td clicked");
}
```

However in my table, I have some td's with checkboxes that when clicked, result in the event firing. Is there a way to specify in Jquery to check if the click inside a td was on a checkbox and don't alert?

Comment: Can you restate the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes the checkbox in question is on the same table row as the clickable cell.

```
$('table tbody td').click( function (e) {

   if(!$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').prop("checked"))
       return;

   alert("td clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell jQuery to stop the checkbox from propagating event from your `checkbox` to your `td`

```
$('table tbody td input[type=checkbox]').click( function (e) {
   // How to check if checkbox was clicked before doing the alert below?
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Basically this happens because when you click on the `checkbox`, browser will bubble that `click` event from your checkbox, to the parent of your checkbox, then go up all the way up to `document`, the code above essentially stops the propagation from your checkbox.

Have a read at [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the eventObject that is passed to the click function to find the target and use that to decide what to do:

```
$("table tbody td").click(function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "INPUT"){
        alert("It's an input!");
    }else{
        alert("It's not an input!");    
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes. This is exactly how I interpreted his question. It sounds like the checkbox is in the td and he wants to prevent a click on it from also triggering the td event. Although I would change it to explicitly check for a checkbox. `e.target.type == 'checkbox'` http://jsfiddle.net/xGpfU/2/

Comment: I left it as input because radio inputs may also fall under this category. A check such as `e.target.type == 'checkbox' || e.target.type == 'radio'` would work as well, if that's what the asker intends